# CSS media print document as brochure

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have documents generated as HTML.
I would like to print these documents as brochures.
I have a problem with printers so I would like to generate CSS and/or HTML to print these documents with proper order, in example, document which have 4 pages:
first page: print  page 4 | 1
second page: print page 2 | 3
Print size : A3.

Is possible to achieve this with only HTML and CSS ?
Component which render these documents is based on IE9, unfortunately :(

Comment: So just to try and clarify, you want to reorder the pages for printing and have the page size as A3? What do you mean print the documents as brochures? You want to convert the file to something like a pdf?

Comment: Brochures means that printed documents are 2 on one page (2 columns), and then, after sheet flex, the content should read as book. I should not using converting. I should print this HTML document as sheet, but with proper page order. User can set page size A3 by himself. I think, changing page order is only way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  to generate different styles for printing. I don't know if responsive printing is possible. But one thing what you can do is ask user for their printer size (by a simple select box)... get the value by javascript and then manipulate  for different sizes...

for eg:

```js
if (//selected for a4) {
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printa4.css" media="print">
} else if (//selected for a3) {
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printa3.css" media="print">
} else {
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printNormal.css" media="print">
}
```

Then manipulate the layout how you want in respective print css files.

May be there is a better way...

Comment: I have different styles for printing. The problem is, that I do not know how, in CSS / HTML, or even JS, to manipulate pages. I try to read W3C CSS3 for something that, but only find in ex. Page Media, but it is limited to margins, orphans, page counters and others ... http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/

Comment: Please view the source code of this website:

http://alokpant.com/demo/pageTest/index.html

This is a sample logic. Once the logic is correct, it will be easier to implement it in different ways too.

The two page printing can be set on the printer properties itself, so when the printing mode is on. Page 1 and 4 will be together. And when it is off, page 4 will be at the end.